# Distribution Profile Currently Matches Ad Hoc

Tags: xcode4, app-store, adhoc, ios-provisioning

How can I change the thing in XCode so that my distribution profile will "currently match" my App Store distribution profile instead of the Ad Hoc one? It's just a pet peeve. I don't do much ad-hoc distribution anymore and so it's annoying to have to select the App Store Provisioning Profile from a drop-down menu every single time I upload to the app store.

I'm using XCode 4.

Answer (score 0):

The only thing that comes to mind is to not make an ad-hoc profile for that app signature.  Or if you already have one on your Mac, delete it.